# How to get gradient border for my hr tag

Tags: html, css

I want **exactly** 50% red color and remaining any another color. I am new for web designing please help me.

```css
hr{
    background: red; 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, yellow); 
    background: -o-linear-gradient(red, yellow); 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(red, yellow);
    background: linear-gradient(red, yellow); 
}
```

```html
<hr style="width:100%; height:5px;">
```

Comment: What is wrong with your current result?

Comment: Exactly **HOW** is this not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are answers of your question

```css
hr{ background: red; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */ 
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, red , yellow); /*For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(right, red, yellow); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */ 
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, red, yellow); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */ 
 background: linear-gradient(to right, red , yellow); /* Standard syntax */ }
.hr2{
    height: 25px;
    background: red; 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red 50%, yellow 50%); 
    background: -o-linear-gradient(red 50%, yellow 50%); 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(red 50%, yellow 50%);
    background: linear-gradient(red 50%, yellow 50%); 
}
```

```html
<hr style="height:10px;">
<hr style="height:10px;" class="hr2">
```

Comment: Thanks For Giving me For This Idea

Comment: You are Welcome

Answer (score 3):

```css
hr{
    height: 20px;
    background: red; 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red 50%, yellow 50%); 
    background: -o-linear-gradient(red 50%, yellow 50%); 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(red 50%, yellow 50%);
    background: linear-gradient(red 50%, yellow 50%); 
}
```

```html
<hr>
```

Comment: Thanks Its Working Fine

Answer (score 0):

```
hr{
  height: 30px; /*Choose your required size*/
  background: red; 
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, red , blue);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(right, red, blue);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, red, blue);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red , blue);
  }
```